# How to call jquery trigger from gwt?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt, strophe

```
  public static native void doConnect() /*-{
            $wnd.jQuery(document).trigger('connect',
                    {
                    jid: 'sss',
                    password: 'sss'
                }

                );

        }-*/;
```

i tried the above ,but there is no error in firebug or gwt hosted mode
console(so i cannot know whether the code is success or not). may i know is this the correct way to call jquery trigger?  but when i put alert() in bind('connect'), it was not called

### inside .js file

```
    $(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) { 
alert('not call.....at all');

        var conn = new Strophe.Connection(
            "http://bosh/xmpp-httpbind");

        conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
            if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger('connected');
            } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger('disconnected');
            }
        });

        Hello.connection = conn;
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had similar issues when using jQuery UI with GWT - no errors in console/dev mode, yet the code did not behave like I wanted. The reason was that jQuery (and such frameworks) extend/change many core elements of JavaScript and expect it to stay that way - however, GWT code (meaning, also JSNI stuff) is executed from a "clean" iframe (so that no external frameworks can mess with the language and cause some weird errors in GWT, that's why you have to reference to the main window via `$wnd`).

I'd suggest moving your `doConnect` function to the host page (or external js file linked to the host page) and instead just call that function from your JSNI stub:

```
public static native void doConnect() /*-{
   $wnd._doConnect('sss','sss'); //_doConnect defined in the host page
}-*/;
```

Or provide helper functions that will return Arrays, etc, from the host page, so that they include all the changes that jQuery made and expects.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit late for this answer, but your original code did not work due to a simple mistake: You have properly used `$win` instead of `window` but a few characters later you have used `document` instead of `$doc` :)

```
public static native void doConnect() /*-{
    $wnd.jQuery($doc).trigger($wnd.jQuery.Event('connect', {
        jid: 'sss',
        password: 'sss'
    }));
}-*/;
```