# Find an element by CSS selector in GWT

Tags: gwt, css-selectors, gquery

I'm trying to grab an arbitrary element using a CSS selector (eg. "#someId .className a") in GWT.

I'm building a JS widget that can live on a 3rd party website and want to be able to interact with elements on the page. Searching through the JavaDocs I don't see anything that can find an element by selector. I did come across GQuery, but it seems like the project [might be dead](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/issues/detail?id=34#c0) and I'm not sure if it works with GWT 2.

One option I've considered is wrapping an existing library (jQuery, Mootools, Prototype, etc) into a GWT class and exposing the desired behavior through JSNI. It seems this might be very builky.

Anyone have experience using generic CSS selectors in GWT?

Comment: GWTQuery/GQuery seems to have been revived and the inactivity would most likely correspond to the release of GWT 2.1.

Comment: It is really frusting to not have the native `querySelector[All]` in GWT. I wonder if this project is doomed being run by people who hate client-side development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the [`DOM`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html) class, that provides many wrapper methods for accessing the DOM tree. There's no function that takes a CSS selector jQuery style that I'm aware of - GWT just encourages/enforces accessing DOM elements through Widgets (and such), not directly - though I understand that in your case such "low-level" approach might be needed. The only way I see pulling that off through pure Java GWT methods is via lots and lots of (probably horrible) chaining/invocations of the `DOM` class. It'd be easier if all you had to do was access some `id` - for that there's [`RootPanel.get(id)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#get(java.lang.String)) (and [`DOM.getElementById(id)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#getElementById(java.lang.String)), they differ in what type of objects they return).

However, like you already suggested, JSNI might offer a better solution - try returning, for example, `$wnd.$("#someId .className a")` from JSNI as an `Element` - actually, you can return anything as anything from JSNI, GWT will just crap up the second you try to use, say an int as a DOM element or something.

PS: while the GQuery project does seem dead/inactive, it might be worth checking how they wrapped the jQuery calls (such as `$`) so that they could be used seemingly in GWT.

Comment: Trying this, I get:  "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method '$'"    do I need jQuery.js on the page also or something?

Comment: Yes, you need to include jQuery .js file in your host page. Also, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2319997/181497), but the `$` should work fine from JSNI.

Comment: I am guessing `document.querySelector(...)` was not an option?

Answer (score 6):

Use GwtQuery, is updated to GWT 2.4: http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/

Selector examples :

```
//select an element having id equals to 'container'
GQuery myElement = $("#container");
//select all elements having 'article' as css class
GQuery allArticles = $(".article");
/select all cells of tables
GQuery allCells = $("table > tr > td");
//find the ul elements being inside a element with class 'article' itself inside a element with id 'container'
GQuery articleUls = $("#container .article ul");
```

http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 3):

You could use querySelector() and querySelectorAll(), available for newer browsers...

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css_selectors_api.shtml

> ...in terms of browser support, querySelector() and querySelectorAll()  is supported in Firefox 3.1+, IE8+ (only in IE8 standards mode), and Safari 3.1+

Comment: `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are not available in GWT. There is a selector rewrite of jQuery available called 'GwtQuery' or 'gQuery'.

Comment: GWT can call any Javascript method you want it to, you just have to write a little wrapper method to act as a pass-through for arguments.  Please see the docs for native method access in the GWT documentation.  This very method was used to access querySelector/querySelectorAll from GWT in my job.

Comment: I wrote myself one-line GWT JSNI wrappers for doc/element querySelector and querySelectorAll and am now using them a lot with excellent results. Easy, reliable and fast.

Comment: Of course you and "add" a property accessor to GWT via JNSI, but that violates the idea of GWT. You want to be able to have GWT build a permutation to work with IE6,7,8, Safari, Gecko 1_8 and older. Poor answer. The question asks how to do this with a GWT function.

Comment: Depends on needs.  Targeting iOS and Android only browsers by developing your app with PhoneGap?  Only need to support WebKit, so use querySelectorAll() .  Targeting a single browser for an internal company app like my old workplace?  Force all your salespeople to run your app on Chrome and use querySelectorAll, they won't notice the difference between a web browser window and a desktop app window.  Easy with the attitude please.

Comment: Excellent solution.

Answer (score 3):

*Inspire by [Asfand Yar Qazi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3164919/980442).*

With [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) you can just define this method and enjoy it when you web app is running in modern browsers.

```
public final native NodeList<Element> querySelectorAll(String selectors) /*-{
 return $doc.querySelectorAll(selectors);
 }-*/;
```

Comment: Does this really work?  Have you tested this? I'd be quite surprised if there is some implicit conversion to NodeList<Element> from a native js return.

Comment: I don't see where your documented source supports this syntax. Please provide a quote.  The closest I can find on that link is within the section "Passing JavaScript values into Java code". For the return type: "any other Java Object (including arrays) ", It states what must be passed is "Java Object of the correct type that must have originated in Java code; Java objects cannot be constructed from “thin air” in JavaScript".  I believe that is in direct opposition to the idea you can implicitly convert return type of a NodeList<Element>.

Comment: Work perfect for me!

Comment: Wow!  Well, I'm surprised, but excited!  That could be very useful.  Nice solution then!  I'll have to try that myself...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the GWT Element and Node classes to find a single nested element with a given class name.  This is not as open ended and powerful as a literal CSS selector, but can be modified as needed for your specific use case:

```
static public Element findFirstChildElementByClassName( Widget w, String className ){
    return findFirstChildElementByClassName( w.getElement(), className );
}
static private Element findFirstChildElementByClassName( Element e, String className ){     
    for( int i=0; i != e.getChildCount(); ++i ){
        Node childNode = e.getChild(i);
        if( childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ){
            Element childElement = (Element)childNode;
            if( childElement.getClassName().equalsIgnoreCase( className ) )
                return childElement;
            else if( childElement.hasChildNodes() ){
                Element grandChildElement = 
                    findFirstChildElementByClassName( 
                            childElement, className );
                if( grandChildElement != null ) return grandChildElement;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```